# FragmentActivity: Cannot cast from Fragment to derived class

Tags: android, casting, android-fragments

I am trying to use a Fragment in a FragmentActivity like so:

```
TutViewerFragment viewer = (TutViewerFragment)    
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.tutview_fragment);
```

And my `TutViewerFragment` extends `Fragment`. However I am getting an error:

> Cannot cast from Fragment to TutViewerFragment.

I really don't understand why this is happening.  Why can't it be cast?

Comment: are you sure that TutViewerFragment is extending Fragment?

Comment: I am positive.  Take a look: http://pastie.org/3534066

Comment: Can you paste your xml <fragment> element? Also what compatibility package are you using?

Comment: Are you sure it extends the right Fragment? There is one in android.app and one in android.support.v4.app...

Comment: @devconsole: You are right!  It was extending the wrong Fragment.  Damn the 'organize imports' feature...

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You are extending the wrong Fragment class. Import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`.

Comment: Or calling `getFragmentManager` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager`.

Comment: Thanks @mattblang could you please elaborate on the difference as well.

Comment: `getFragmentManager` returns a native Fragment, whereas `getSupportFragmentManager` returns a support Fragment. `getSupportFragmentManager` is part of/added by the support library because they cannot change the return type of the existing method.

Answer (score 7):

As **devconsole** pointed out in the comment above: The class that extends Fragment needs to import

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

and not

```
android.app.Fragment;
```

I guess it has to do with the Android Compatibility Package.  Problem is now resolved!

Answer (score 5):

Just in case people are looking for kotlin equivalent:

```
myFragmentClass = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment) as MyFindOfFragment
```

Comment: AS flags the 'as' as "this cast can never succeed".
I'm importing android.support.v4.app.Fragment in every fragment.

Answer (score 3):

As **devconsole/igor** specified, we need to ensure the Fragment class used in both classes is same.
i.e. andorid.app.Fragment in both

```
public class WorkoutDetailFragment extends Fragment
```

and in the Activity class where we try to get reference of the fragment.

```
WorkoutDetailFragment workoutDetailFragment = (WorkoutDetailFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
```

Ensuring the same Fragment class in both files will resolve class cast exception.

Hope this helps. I know its a bit late. I am new to Android and exploring the nuances of the wonderful language. Thanks to Stackoverflow for helping me with resolving these minor issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you get this and are importing `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` check that you use **support**FragmentManager and **Not** fragmentManager.

Kotlin:

```
//DO
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment

myFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment) as MyFragment

//DON'T
import android.app.Fragment

myFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment) as MyFragment
```

Java:

```
//DO
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment

myFragment =(MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment)

//DON'T
import android.app.Fragment

myFragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment)
```