# Why can I not cast from Fragment to MyOwnFragment?

Tags: java, android, xml, casting, android-fragments

I've got a fragment which I obviously extend from the fragment class as follows:

```
public class MyOwnFragment extends Fragment {
```

Then, in my LoginActivity (defined as `public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {`), I try to call this fragment like so:

```
final MyOwnFragment thefragment = (MyOwnFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_my_own);
```

Unfortunately, this results in an error saying:

```
Cannot cast from Fragment to MyOwnFragment
```

I would not know why this is. Anybody any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Are you extending from the right Fragment class?

Comment: Make sure you're importing the proper `Fragment` class, either from the compatibility package or the native sdk one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586218/fragmentactivity-cannot-cast-from-fragment-to-derived-class?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this link [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586218/fragmentactivity-cannot-cast-from-fragment-to-derived-class) Please make sure that you import correct Fragment class.
Please try to Import

> android.support.v4.app.Fragment

instead of

> android.app.Fragment

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get a `Fragment`  by calling `getSupportFragmentManager` try `getFragmentManager()` or change  `android.app.Fragment` to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in your imports.